# You need different package name because this name already exists in play store

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-play, google-play-services

google delete my play store account now i am uploading my application from new account but it is showing error that this name already exits.if i change my package name it is also connected to google-services.jason(firebase realtime database) but i cannot change firebase path because application users already using application with old package name and database
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> Google delete my Play Store account now I am uploading my application from a new account.

If they deleted your account, it's because you infringed some rules for your app, Google will give you warnings if your app needs something to change, if your account has been deleted is because your app is not able to be in the Play Store

Please check: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/

**About the question**

You can't change a package name of an existing app in the playstore once you upload it, if you try to have the same package name in another account, you can't upload that apk, you can change the package at your project level and in Firebase, but if you are trying to upload again your app and has been already uploaded in another account, you can't upload it again.

Comment: then what is solution??

Comment: "If they deleted your account, it's because you infringed some rules for your app" -
Google also deletes accounts due to inactivity, which can lead to the exact same issue.